# After click on embed YT video bigger screen

Tags: javascript, css, youtube

I embed youtbude video on my site, allow fullscreen, its work good. But i want, when user click on that youtube video,  automatically increase the video screen (from 600px to 900px for example). Is it possible to do this, maybe with CSS/JS?

My code:

```
   <div class="video"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kDYZ_HiSuMk" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: I don’t think you should try that with the iframe version - that might be interpreted as an attempt at click jacking. Embed the video using their JS API instead - then you can subscribe to certain events, such as the user starting/pausing the video, etc.